# Wordpress Adding a top-level menu item that integrates two forms

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm just getting into wordpress and I need to add a new top-level admin menu item: Vehicles, using my own custom php code without using the plugins: Custom Post Type UI and Advanced Custom Fields.

There are two items/terms below Vehicles: Cars and Trucks respectively.

When this menu item is clicked or hovered over: I need it to give me the option to add a car or a truck on one page. Note that the car has its own attributes and a truck has its own different attributes and I will have a submit button for both the car and truck forms so that I can just submit the truck attributes without having to fill in car attributes since there are some fields in car that are required.

I have checked the wordpress codex and found this on creating a custom type:

```
 add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
  function create_post_type() {
   register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

I guess I will have to create a new php file and call it vehicle.php and past the above code inside.
Where would I save this file and how would I get it to be called by wordpress' core when wordpress is running? Or is there a way to do that with the above plugins where I will have two different forms: car and truck forms in the menu item: vehicle

Comment: Just been doing this too; how I did it, I copied the single.php codes and make my own single-{post_type}.php in your case single-cars/trucks.php. The page will retrieve the information from cars/truck post_type.

Comment: nCore. Thanks. i had to study the theme-template hierarchy on the codex to understand your answer

Comment: Mutuma, Cool hope you'll get your way around it the codex definitely helps. Mind giving my reply a thumbs up if you find it helpful by clicking the up arrow next to my reply. Ty and Goodluck.